# How to setup jenkins blue ocean under Windows with docker agent

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run a simple jenkins pipeline under windows 10 using the docker agent. My environment:

- Running latest Jenkins from cli (java -jar jenkins)
- Git.exe and docker.exe in path, both working correctly.

My Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'maven:3.5.0'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Hello') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn --version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result is as it never even tries to run docker:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Agent Setup)
[Pipeline] sh
[C:\Users\amoya\.jenkins\workspace\oya_sampleapp_jenkins-setup-FIF55WR7GZ32BUQR22LYEG2ZKBHHCXBCQH76TBZYJSB3TNTZCV7A] Running shell script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Complete output: https://gist.github.com/adrianmoya/bf01d97090c4b9de7fd27db31ecfc837

It's like trying to run sh in windows, completely ignoring the docker agent setup. Under linux it pulls down the image and runs succesfully. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running the docker daemon at?

If it's on localhost try setting your global DOCKER_HOST env variable to tcp://ip.of.docker.daemon:port

You can also set this manually in the Jenkins config

Also it appears that it's trying to launch shell commands in Windows without much success... perhaps you can try 'batch' instead of 'sh' ? (This doesn't make sense in the context of running shell in a non-Windows container though)

Another option would be to run a Jenkins node in Virtualbox or Hyper-V to do all the docker building/running, and use the nodes label.